# php menu and multilanguage page

Tags: php, session, menu, multilingual

I am developing a multi-language website with php. I used session to take language change request from users.

```
<?php
$check_lang=array("eng","suo","sve");

session_start();

if(isset($_GET["lang"])){
    if(in_array($_GET["lang"], $check_lang)){
        $_SESSION["lang"]=$_GET["lang"];
    }

}
if($_SESSION["lang"]==""){
    $_SESSION["lang"]="eng";
}
include("Lang/".$_SESSION["lang"]."/".$_SESSION["lang"].".php");
?>
```

This works pretty well. But the problem is that once the user navigates different menu(say "About" in English) and presses a link to change language to Swedish, the page redirects to "home" in Swedish.

I would like to know how to record which page user is currently and change that particular page on language change request.

-thanks on advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can use $_SERVER["HTTP_REFERER"] to see where people are coming from. People can actually change this so make sure you build some security so people don't get redirected to other domains etc.